# Time complexity of a recursive function called variably in a loop

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

What will be the time complexity of this function:

```
 public int calculate(int[] arr, int index) {
  int max = 0, sum = 0;
  for (int i = index; i < arr.length && i < index + arr[index]; i++) {
    sum += arr[i];
    max = Math.max(max, calculate(arr, i + 1));
  }
  return Math.max(max, sum);
}
```

The fucntion gets called with an array and an index. As the function makes arr[index] recursive calls to itself, can we say that its time complexity is O(max(arr)^n) ('n' being number of elements in arr)? Is it possible to find a tigher limit? The time complexity is definitely not 2^n, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's first remove the `i < index + arr[index]` part from the loop condition, which would only (sometimes) reduce the number of iterations. By removing it, we can get a worst case.

As in each loop iteration the function is called, counting the number of times the function is executed (at any recursion depth), is a good measure for the time complexity. Let's call this count *c*.

Now define *k* as the number of iterations of the loop without taking recursion into account, so *k* is `arr.length - i`

*c* depends on *k*, so let's speak of *c<sub>k</sub>*

For *k* = 0 there is no iteration, so just the single call, so *c<sub>0</sub> = 1*. We can continue for increasing *k*:

*c<sub>1</sub> = 1 + c<sub>0</sub> = 2*
          *c<sub>2</sub> = 1 + c<sub>0</sub> + c<sub>1</sub> = 2c<sub>1</sub> = 4*
          *c<sub>3</sub> = 1 + c<sub>0</sub> + c<sub>1</sub> + c<sub>2</sub> = 2c<sub>2</sub> = 8*
          ...
          *c<sub>k</sub> = 1 + ∑<sup>k-1</sup><sub>i=0</sub>(c<sub>i</sub>) = 1 + ∑<sup>k-2</sup><sub>i=0</sub>(c<sub>i</sub>) + c<sub>k-1</sub> = 2.c<sub>k-1</sub> = 2<sup>k</sup>*

When you call the function with `i=0`, and define *n* as `arr.length` then the conclusion is that the function has a time complexity of *O(2<sup>n</sup>)*